# How to remove url text from page printed using javascript's window.print() function

Tags: javascript

Here is my code where I am opening a new window by clicking on a anchor tag.
It navigates to try1.php and once clicking on it, it will go to try1.php. (The code is given in the second code.

try.php

```
     <script type="text/javascript">
     function newwin() 
     {
       myWindow=window.open('try1.php','myWin','width=400,height=650')
      }
   </script>
   </head>
   <body>
   <a onclick="newwin()">click </a>
   </body>
```

The code for try1.php is given below

```
   <body>
   <input type="submit" value="print Data"  onClick="window.print()"/>
   </body>
```

in try1.php, I am having a button on which I have apllied onclcck event.
When I click on the button it prints the data but also prints the url text which I don't want.

May I know the way to remove the url text from the printed page?

Comment: Adjust the browser print settings.

Comment: http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/the-geek-blog/prevent-firefox-or-internet-explorer-from-printing-the-url-on-every-page/

Comment: is there any other way like is there  any code to remove that ???

Comment: @user3138522 you can do that with media-dependent style sheets. See my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that with [media-dependent style sheets](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/media.html) like below;

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="print,handheld" href="your.css"/>
```

And in your `your.css`;

```
@media print {
    a {
        display:none;
    }
 }

 @media screen and projection {
    a {
        display:inline;
    }
  }
```

Comment: i tried it...but links are still getting showed...this cpde writing made no difference...

Comment: Have you added css to your printed file?

Comment: can u suggest me something for it??

Comment: Last way, you need to disable it from browser settings

Comment: can we disable settings from firefox and chrome both??

Comment: Each browser has own settings

Comment: i have already made changes for firefox but is this also possible in chrome??

Comment: Yes it is browser based setting.you need to do it for each browser

Comment: could you please tell me how to do these settings in chrome??

Comment: In settings, select "print", in print dialog page unselect "Header and footers" on left pane

Comment: in settings i cannot find the print option??